# Refused to frame '<URL>' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 'frame-ancestors 'self'

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am currently developing a Chrome extension and have successfully configured AWS Connect Stream within my application using approved URLs.

However, when integrating the same configuration into the Chrome extension, I am facing issues with AWS Connect Stream functionality.The error message I'm encountering is:

> Refused to frame '<URL>' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 'frame-ancestors 'self'."

Could you please provide guidance on any specific configurations or adjustments required for AWS Connect Stream to function correctly within a Chrome extension?

This is my code, I am trying to initiate aws-connect-stream.

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "amazon-connect-streams";

function App() {
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const containerDiv = containerRef.current;
    const instanceURL = "InstanceURL";

    connect.core.initCCP(containerDiv as HTMLDivElement, {
      ccpUrl: instanceURL,
      loginPopup: true,
      loginPopupAutoClose: true,
      loginOptions: {
        autoClose: true,
        height: 600,
        width: 400,
        top: 0,
      },
      region: "your-region",
      softphone: {
        allowFramedSoftphone: true,
      },
      pageOptions: {
        enableAudioDeviceSettings: true,
        enablePhoneTypeSettings: true,
      },
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        padding: 16,
      }}
    >
      <div
        ref={containerRef}
        id="ccp"
        style={{ width: 400, height: 800 }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Also I've added headers in config

```
 headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the Url of your application into Amazon Connect instance. Go to AWS Console then open Amazon Connect instance that you are using, in right hand side menu there is **Approved Origin** option. There you need to allow your urls of your app.

Comment: I possess what you're saying, but I'm implementing an extension into use, and it only has the extension ID and no URL.